# Изменить формат даты Java Android

Tags: java, android, дата

Есть строка даты примерно такая: `Fri, 22 Apr 2016 15:29:51 +0600`

Мне ее нужно сделать такой: `22.04.2016 15:29:51`

Как можно это сделать на android? Подскажите как сделать, и если знаете ссылку на статью где можно научится работать с датами и временем.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

так попробуйте

```
String date = "Fri, 22 Apr 2016 15:29:51 +0600"; 

SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss Z"); 
SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.M.yyyy HH:mm:ss");

try { 

    Date res = df.parse(date); 
    String formattedTime = output.format(d); // Это результат

} catch (ParseException e1) { }
```

если нужно указать язык сделайте так

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss zzzz", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

> Комментарий от CJ1 - Вот оказывается где полный список возможного формата! **[Ссылка](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)**

Comment: Вот оказывается где полный список возможного формата! http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

```
Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss");
String folderName = formatter.format(today);
System.out.println(folderName);
```